# What is the difference between embedded entity and a serialized text/blob?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Since embedded entity fields cannot be indexed, I see no difference between using an embedded entity and serializing an object to a text/blob (in whatever format I want). The only benefit I can think of is that using embedded entities I get out of the box consistent mapping with the low level API and frameworks such as Objectify. Is there anything I'm missing? I'm asking because I wanted to store an embedded entity in a way currently not supported by Objectify, and I'm trying to figure out if I should alter my classes to fit Objectify so I can use embedded entities or just serialize them as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields can't be indexed yet, but may be indexable in the future. The main advantage is the Datastore (and the various datastore client libraries) understands the format, so embedded entities benefit from new features as they are added.

Comment: Looks like embedded entities can be indexed now